# Converting C++ class to procedural API: common way of replacing member variables?

Tags: c++, c, global-variables, member, procedural-programming

I'm converting a C++ class, let's call it `render`, which only ever had one instance used (singleton-but-not-offically), to a purely procedural style for use in a C program. Which being what it is, a simple software renderer, probably should have been written as such in the first place.

The ex-class mostly just dealt with a ton of generically-named private variables, everything from lone bytes to large arrays of binary data. `unsigned char frame_counter`, `char* frame_data`, `unsigned char palette[256][128][3]`, etc. which is what I'm trying to replace.

I'm renaming my functions in a simple way, like: `render::load_sprite(const char* file)` -> `render_load_sprite(const char* file)`

Global "member" variables:

- Generally considered bad / to be avoided. *Possible* conflicts at some point.
- Don't know how I should rename members. Maybe prefix like `renderer_palette`? Kinda verbose from the inside.
- What if I want some variables to modifiable without wrapper function?

State struct:

- OOP-like, but I'm dealing with what should a singular, static API.
- Has to be passed around everywhere. Kinda verbose from the outside.
- Has to be initialized.

Is the preferred choice in this instance globals, struct, or is there another option?

Comment: Why are you converting to C?

Comment: In c++ the singleton is best implemented by replacing the class by a namespace and data member by static data member (internal linkage). I would do the same in C, without the namespace.

Comment: If you have to change to C, I like the struct better than 'loose' variables.  Passing around a pointer to the struct is not burdensome.  If you don't want set/getters for the 'loose' variables, they will have to be declared extern in files that need to 'see' them.  Then you will deal with all of the pains of uncontrollable side effects caused by a bunch of loose global variables visible to anybody and everybody.  Seems like a big step backward to me.

Comment: As mentioned, you would probably be better off explaining what you are trying to accomplish by the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Eeek.. Globals? Shoot yourself. Never use globals. Big no no. Ruins reentrancy and kills your code.

All C code I write looks like this:

```
struct object {
    int data;
};

void object_init(struct object *self);
void object_update(struct object *self, float dt);
int object_write_to_file(struct object *self, const char *file);
```

- for anything that is not trivial like radians(float degrees) use a struct and pass it as first argument called `self` everywhere (do not use `this` even if allowed in C because you will have problems mixing with C++)
- keep file name and struct name the same
- prefix all methods that operate on the struct with struct name
- do not use typedef struct ... it makes glancing over code harder
- always keep all data in structs that stem from a root application object. ie struct application { struct object obj; ... }. This allows you to easily make as many instances of the application as you like (provided that all libraries you use also are designed as OOP objects without static state). Regardless, it is a good practice for your code.
- Doing this allows you to have full control over: reentrancy, data locality, data ownership, data modification, code readability. Generally you get much better quality too and can easily make your app multithreaded because without global state everything that needs to be locked is inside the same struct.
- Over time you start to appreciate verbosity a lot because EVERYTHING you do with your code becomes easier and you can understand what the code does just by looking at it. You know that self->member is a reference to a variable that is passed to current method. You know this variable is local to the object. You know self is the object you are currently operating on. You know that any access to members of self probably has to be locked by a lock called self->lock if mutual exclusion is necessary. Easy inferences like these really speed up development time and make your life easier.

Comment: Never say never. Oops, I did it :-) There are certainly areas where globals make sense *and* are more convenient than other solutions without sacrificing readability or maintainability. Not in large complex code with lots of dependencies, no doubt, but there *are* places. Also I "coded" `self`/`this` in your first bullet point since, on first reading, it seemed you were suggesting something and then telling us we shouldn't do it :-) Other than that, good answer, since you're basically doing what C++ does but using the C mindset (explicitly and painfully).

Comment: It's not that painful. Instead actually extremely well readable. Linux kernel is a good example.